# Avoiding RTTI In Java

Tags: java, oop, rtti

If I have a superclass, say **Animal**,

and two subclasses: **Zebra** and **Giraffe**,

If I decide to define a Vector of Animals:

```
Vector <Animal> animals = new Vector();
```

and I want to say: You can add **Giraffes**, but you must own at least one **Zebra** first.

What is the best way to do this without using RTTI? (*instanceof*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your own class:

```
class Animals extends Vector<Animal>
{
   public Animals(Zebra z) { add(z); }
}
```

Two additional points:

- It is recommended to prefer the use of ArrayList over Vector.
- You may want to override the remove() method to make sure a Zebra always stays in the collection.

Personally, I would go for a design that does not use inheritance at all. So instead of subclassing vector (or ArrayList) my class will delegate to them:

```
class Animals extends 
{
   private final Vector<Animal> inner = new Vector<Animal>();

   public Animals(Zebra z) { add(z); }

   // Delegate to whatever methods of Vector that Animals need to support, e.g.,
   void add(Animal a) { inner.add(a); }

   ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending delegation in place of inheritance as well as for pointing out that ArrayList is preferred over Vector.